# How to upload Image Buffer data in AWS S3?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to upload buffer data from an image into S3. It gets uploaded fine. But when I try to download/view the image in S3, it throws an error. I have tried the following -

1. The image is available to me in Buffer format (JSON). I cannot change this

```js
let image = { "type": "Buffer", "data": [45, 45, 45....]

let buf = new Buffer(image )

let params = {
  Bucket: "bucketName",
  Key: "TestImage123haha.PNG",
  Body: buf ,
  ACL: 'public-read',
  ContentType: 'image/jpeg'
};

s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('ERROR MSG: ', err);
  } else {
    console.log('Successfully uploaded data' + data.Location);
  }
})
```

2. After upoading the image if I try to visit the URL of the bucket where it is stored and view the image, this is what I get -

[image: Response]

3. When I print the buffer data - `buf` in console , this is what I get -

[image: Result of printing Buffer data in console]

Comment: To be clear, are you doing `let buf = new Buffer(image )` or `let buf = new Buffer(image.data)`?

Comment: I have tried both. image.data contain the binary content + the headers that you see in the image attached.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this issue?

Comment: I faintly remember trying to remove the headers in the response (check image attached) and then uploading it. Sorry don't remember the details exactly as it is year-old, however, headers were the issue which I am pretty certain of.

Comment: @BoudhayanDev Could you please share what was the exact solution? I already spent two weeks. If you share this, it will be very much helpful for me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This problem took me many days but I was able to solve it:

In your API GATE WAY of funtion lambda go to Configuration > Binary types.

[image]

Add multipart/form-data

Comment: As per the above question, Buffer(image) OR Buffer(image.data) need to set as body?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I can help someone solve this problem.

I just trimmed the base64 string like this:

```
const base64Str = post.image.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, '')
const bufferImage = Buffer.from(base64Str, 'base64');
```

And also here is my code for uploading a file to aws s3:

```
import { S3 } from 'aws-sdk'

class AwsS3Service {
  private s3: S3;
  private readonly bucketName: string;

  constructor() {
    this.s3 = new S3({
      accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
      secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY,
      region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
    });
    this.bucketName = process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME;
  }

  async uploadImage(fileBuffer: Buffer, fileName: string): Promise<string> {
    const params: S3.Types.PutObjectRequest = {
      Bucket: this.bucketName,
      Key: fileName,
      Body: fileBuffer,
      ACL: 'public-read',
    };

    try {
      const result = await this.s3.upload(params).promise();
      return result.Location || '';
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error uploading image to S3:', error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
}

export default AwsS3Service;
```

Here is my code for calling the function to load an image and get the imageUrl:

```
const base64Str = post.image.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, '')
const bufferImage = Buffer.from(base64Str, 'base64');
const fileName = `${nanoid(25)}.${type.split('/')[1]}`
const imageUrl = await awsS3Service.uploadImage(bufferImage, fileName)
```

Also this site helped me a lot: https://medium.com/yavar/amazon-s3-bucket-image-upload-using-node-js-f1fe58183a88